# Resize TableView Height after

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView inside a regular ViewController and I'd like to adjust the tableview's entire height.

I created the tableview through storyboard, and I'm loading data from an API in my `ViewDidLoad`. I set up the cells in the typical tableview method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.loadPerformers()
    setupTableView(performersTableView)
}

func setupTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == self.performersTableView {
            let performerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PerformerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PerformersTableViewCell
            let performer = self.performersArray[indexPath.row]
            performerCell.performerPic.image = getPerformerImage(performer.english_name)
            performerCell.performerName.text = performer.english_name + "   " + performer.japanese_name
            cell = performerCell
    }
    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count:Int?

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.allowsSelection = false

    if tableView == self.performersTableView {
        count = self.performersArray.count
    }

    return count!

}
```

The problem I'm having is the tableview stays the same height after loading the data. Below I'm loading four items, but it's only showing 2. The tableview height doesn't change.

[image]

I've tried a few things, among them is changing the height of the tableview frame in the `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let newHeight = self.performersTableView.rowHeight * CGFloat(self.numberOfPerformers)

    self.performersTableView.frame = CGRectMake(performersTableView.frame.origin.x, performersTableView.frame.origin.y,
        performersTableView.frame.size.width, newHeight)
}
```

This does nothing though, so I'm misunderstanding something in the rendering process. How do I redisplay the table with my desired height?

Comment: Is the tableview created in a storyboard/xib?

Comment: Did you set numberOfRowsInSection to self.performersArray.count ?

Comment: show what you want to achieve, do you want to change the tableview height based on the number of row? or just want to make it look like design by increasing some height?

Comment: Yes. I'll add that to my question. It's created in storyboard but I add some setup code I'll add now.

Comment: If you are talking about adjusting the height of each table view cell, have a look at this. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @Slamice Create an outlet connection from the NSLayoutConstraint in the storyboard that controls the height of the table, to your code. You can then modify that line by saying `<constraint-name>.constant = <some height>`. Do this in the `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: @Dylan yes I did, I added that code here.

Comment: Do remember to add `self.performersTableView.reloadData()` after adding performer into your performersArray

Comment: @Dylan Yea I tried adding that, no dice.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 solutions for your problem:

1. If you want to set height of Tableview based on Tableview Cells.
   so first of when you get data from server Reload your Tableview and after reloading tableview you will get content height of Filled tableview using this code:

   ```
   self.performersTableView.contentSize.height
   ```

   then set this height as your tableview frame.
2. In design, set fix height of tableview and set reference of constraint  and after reloading tableview:

   ```
   self.performersTableViewHeightReference.constant = self.performersTableView.contentSize.height
   ```

I hope this helps You.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.theTableView setNeedsLayout];
[self.theTableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Add this code in your `setupTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` is data count. And if you want to expend cell also according to content write code in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`: `cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;`